# How to pass parameters to components rendered offline?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, tapestry

I have MyComponent:

```
public class MyComponent
{
    @Parameter(required = false)
    @Property
    private String testParameter;
}
```

And I render it offline with the following code:

```
PageRenderRequestParameters pageRenderRequestParameters = new PageRenderRequestParameters(
            "mycomponent", new ArrayEventContext(this.typeCoercer, ""), false);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
try
{
    this.offlineComponentRenderer.renderPage(stringWriter,
                new DefaultOfflineRequestContext(), pageRenderRequestParameters);
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String htmlOutput = stringWriter.toString();
```

I don't know how to set the `testParameter` of `MyComponent` to imitate the following call:

```
<t:mycomponent testParameter="something" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you failed to mention that you're using [tapestry-offline](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-offline), a 3rd party tapestry library.

You will need to create a page which includes the component before it can be rendered. If you want to make the parameter configurable, you will probably [bind](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters#ComponentParameters-ParameterBindings) the property to the [page activation context](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/PageActivationContext.html)

Note: If you don't want the page to be visible on your website, you could probably annotate it with [WhitelistAccessOnly](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/WhitelistAccessOnly.html) and tweak the [offline request](https://github.com/uklance/tapestry-offline#appmodule) so that it is whitelisted.